Reverse routing issue with Cakephp-4.x
I am experiencing problems with routing on cakephp 4.x
I have a connector in routes.php like this :
$routes->connect(
        '/achat-vente-location/licences-{type}/departement/{slug}/{id}', 
        [
            'controller' => 'Licences', 
            'action' => 'departement', 
            'prefix' => null
        ]
    )
    ->setPatterns(
        [
            'id' => '[0-9]+', 
            'type' => 3
        ]
    )
    ->setPass(
        [
            'id', 
            'type',
            'slug'
        ]
    );

In my view, I am trying to generate the correct url with reverse routing expected like this :
Router::url([
    'controller' => 'Licences', 
    'action' => 'departement', 
    'type' => 3, 
    'slug' => 'Slug', 
    'id' => 33321
]);

But it does not generate the good URL and I do not know why. I get this URL :
https://localhost/licences/departement

What is expected :
https://localhost/achat-vente-location/licences-3/departement/Slug/33321


Problem solved !!
You have to mention the 'prefix' parameter in the URL build like this :
Router::url([
    'controller' => 'Licences', 
    'action' => 'departement',
    'prefix' => null, 
    'type' => 3, 
    'slug' => 'Slug', 
    'id' => 33321
]);

